# IDs not being recognized when placed in modals

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am creating a registration form where its contents are contained in DIV (hidden), then when the user clicks a button, the modal shows and the content is loaded through the ID of the DIV.

However, I am encountering a problem where the button of the DIV is not recognized in my script. I assigned a click event using jquery, but it doesn't work. Probably because the hidden DIV has conflicts with the DIV create in the modal (which will eventually have the same IDs).

Here is my script:

```
$('#addCollege').click(function(e){
    modal.open({content: $('#addCollegeForm').html()});
    e.preventDefault();`
});
```

This is the DIV

```
<div id="addCollegeForm" style="display:none">
    <label>College:</label><br>
    <input type="text" placeholder = "Enter college name here..." id = "collegeDescription" > <br>
    <input type="button" value="Save" id= "addCollege">
</div>
```

Thanks and I appreciate your help.

Comment: it appears that the button used to open your dialog is inside your dialog...?

Comment: Looks like you probably have duplicate id's. you might want to do something about that. like, make them not duplicate.

Comment: Kevin, you are correct. I am having duplicate IDs. How can I resolve that? This is where I downloaded the modal plugin.

http://www.jacklmoore.com/notes/jquery-modal-tutorial/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a dialog plugin for bootstrap, and got a similar problem.
I want to pop up an existing dom element.

Here is solution:

```
$targetElement.detach().appendTo($window.find('.modal-body')) // $targetElement is an existing dom
```

Detach element and append it to container.

Don't forget to revert the element to old container.
Hope it helps.

Regards

Comment: Thanks for your help. I was not successful in using appendTo because I am using a modal created by another user. However, using the detach was a success. Although I had to do some workarounds to make it work. Here's what I did:

`var obj = $('#addCollegeForm');`
`$('#addCollegeForm').detach();`
`var mod = modal.open({content: obj.html() });`

Comment: You'd better to use old element, instead of it's html. There may be some events or bindings(knockout).

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the button that opens your dialog out of the dialog:

EDIT - something like this should work...

HTML...

```
<div id="addCollegeForm">things in your dialog</div>
<input type="button" value="open dialog" id="addCollege">
```

jquery...

```
$("#addCollegeForm").dialog({
    autoOpen: false
});


$('#addCollege').click(function () {
    $("#addCollegeForm").dialog("open");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/DTq6m/

http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-autoOpen

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I can open the modal, however, the button inside the modal that saves the data to the DB is not recognized because it has duplicate IDs.